# friendly_id scope unique to parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, slug, friendly-id

Is it possible to scope the slug to the parent resource so that two users can share the same resource slug?  example:

two users would have news articles "i-am-awesome"

domain/joe/news/i-am-awesome
domain/sara/news/i-am-awesome

I've made a custom validation for the slug for uniquiness on user's resource, but this still ends up generating a UUID for the second user.  ends up being:

domain/sara/news/i-am-awesome-UUID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be too late to help, but yes, you can scope friendly_id. From the [documentation](https://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Scoped.html):

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :city
  friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  has_many :restaurants
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
end

City.friendly.find("seattle").restaurants.friendly.find("joes-diner")
City.friendly.find("chicago").restaurants.friendly.find("joes-diner")
```